# how to format date from mysql database inside SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named `date_posted` in MySQL database in the form of `2014-11-22 12:45:34` . I need to get only the date, month and year. So, I do

```
SELECT DATE(date_posted) as date_p FROM tablename
```

So, I get a format as `2014-11-22`. How can I get it in the form 22 Nov, 2014.
And can it still be used for sorting the results.

Thank you :D !

Comment: Try the DATE_FORMAT function, as found on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering [this:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_posted, '%d %b, %Y')
```

And no, this can't be used directly for sorting. You can ,however, parse it to date and then sort later.

```
order by str_to_date(text_date, '%d %b, %Y')
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try **`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_posted, '%d %b, %Y') as your_date FROM table_name`**

To get more idea about DATE_FORMAT() refer given link.

**http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp**